# Get only instance related Items in Django Admin

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-models, django-admin

I am new to python and Django so I hope I can get some help here.
I have an "app" where I have some models like "Raum", "Platz" and "Buchung". in English (Room, Postion and booking). In the web app a user can book a Position in a Room.
Here are my 3 Models.

Room:

```
class Raum(models.Model):
    raumID = models.CharField(max_length=1, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='')
```

Position:

```
class Platz(models.Model):
    platzID = models.CharField(max_length=3, primary_key=True)
    raum = models.ForeignKey(Raum, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
```

Booking:

```
class Buchung(models.Model):

cearted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     user = models.ForeignKey(Mitarbeiter, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
     raum = models.ForeignKey(Raum, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
     platz = models.ForeignKey(Platz, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
```

I want to be able to choose a Room and a Position when trying to book a Room. But it should only show the positions for the room I choose. And thats my Problem, I don't really know how to do that. I looked into the Django documentation and found "to_field" but I don't think thats right and also it doesn't work.

[Booking in admin page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13vHz.png)

So as u can see I have a Room(raum) called "seestern" and a Position(Platz) it shows 4 choices. But Room Seestern has Only "A1" and "A2". I want to only display those that belongs to a room.
How can I do that?

Hopefully I get some Help.
Thanks.

Comment: That's a bit problematic to implement. The problem is that both drop downs are available all the time. What if user will firstly select a Platz? Also,  what if user changes Raum after selecting a Platz? This type of functionality is better done with some custom page with assistance of JS to implement dynamic fields.

Comment: Well Platz should always be selected after a Room selection. But yeah I get where this is going, so there is no option to "refresh" the options ins platz right?

Comment: In Django core -  no.  Once the form is rendered,  each field's choices are static. Try to look for some 3rd party packages here https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/admin-interface/. Take a look a this https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/,  it might have what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#filtering-results-based-on-the-value-of-other-fields-in-the-form.  It seems to do the thing you want to achieve. It requires you to write some logic manually,  but still does a great job on frontend so you don't have to deal with JavaScript and HTML of admin panel. Create the form for you model and add it to your admin class like `form=MyForm`.  Try to follow the documentation from the beginning and then apply the technique described in the link I have provided, because if you jump straight to it you will be a bit overwhelmed.

Comment: This looks really good. But well I already started with the Javascript way that you told me about. But I will try to also try this autocomplete way later. Thank you for the Help.